# Spring JPA - Page<Company> - append Page contents

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Inside a for loop I have my 'Page companies' object which stores the result of method called 'findByNameOrGroupIdOrTerritoryIdAndCompanyIdsInobject' 'n' number of times. If it was a List we could go with companies.addAll() method so that it would append to the same object.

Is there any way to append to companies object instead of assigning every time which only stores last iteration result?

Here is the code snippet:

```
Page<Company> companies = null;
int parametersLimit = 500;
int companyBatches = companyIds.size() / parametersLimit;
for (int companyBatchIndex = 0; companyBatchIndex <= companyBatches; companyBatchIndex++) {
    int lowerIndex = companyBatchIndex * parametersLimit;
    int upperIndex = Math.min((companyBatchIndex + 1) * parametersLimit, companyIds.size());
    companies = companyRepository.findByNameOrGroupIdOrTerritoryIdAndCompanyIdsIn(nameOrGroupId, territoryId, companyIds.subList(lowerIndex, upperIndex), pageable);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand you question

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: updated the description. Please check now.

Comment: I stil don't understand what you want do. Can you please explain your requirement?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: updated the question once again. Basically I need to append to Page object similar to List object using addAll() in for loop.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because findByNameOrGroupIdOrTerritoryIdAndCompanyIdsIn() is a @Query which fetches me Page<Company> and we pass company IDs in that query (using IN clause) and when company IDs are more than 2100, it fails (limitation from SQL). So we split the company IDs in a group of 500 and then send execute the query. So this is the reason we need for loop and we need to append the result to Page object.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a list you should not use page like this

Comment: No, I can't. I need the Page object only as I have pagination logic applied.

Comment: You can use pageImpl for that

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, there is no such way to append to Page contents. So I modified the logic to return List of Companies and then using PageImpl I converted the List to Page.

```
Page<Company> companies = null;
List<Company> companiesList = new ArrayList<Company>();;
int parametersLimit = 500;
int companyBatches = companyIds.size() / parametersLimit;
for (int companyBatchIndex = 0; companyBatchIndex <= companyBatches; companyBatchIndex++) {
    int lowerIndex = companyBatchIndex * parametersLimit;
    int upperIndex = Math.min((companyBatchIndex + 1) * parametersLimit, companyIds.size());
    companiesList.addAll(companyRepository.findByNameOrGroupIdOrTerritoryIdAndCompanyIdsIn(nameOrGroupId, territoryId, companyIds.subList(lowerIndex, upperIndex), pageable));
}

int fromIndex = pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize();
int toIndex =  Math.min( (int) (pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize()), companiesList.size());

companies = new PageImpl<>(companiesList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex), pageable, companiesList.size());
```